# How to fix UITableView separator on iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, ios7

UITableView draws with ragged lines on iOS 7:

[image]

How to fix it? The line between cells should be on the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 489, accepted):

`UITableView` has a property `separatorInset`. You can use that to set the insets of the table view separators to zero to let them span the full width of the screen.

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

**Note:** If your app is also targeting other iOS versions, you should check for the availability of this property before calling it by doing something like this:

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Comment: Please correct answer to: `    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
`

Comment: In which method should I write this line? Doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can call this method on your table view in `viewDidLoad`.
If your table view is create programmatically, you should create an IBOutlet in order to get a reference to it.

Comment: @s1m0n any idea how you also remove the padding to the left and right of cell.imageViews in in iOS7? If you look at the 1st questions image I have the same issue..I tried setting the imageViews frame but made no difference?

Comment: This did not work for me. But this worked : ```if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorStyle:)]) {
        [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    }```

Comment: it's working very successful. I have white line on tableview , now ı haven't . thank a lot :)

Comment: note to others: doesn't work from initWithStyle - I popped it in viewDidLoad and it works great

Comment: Note that if you have written your own UITableViewCell subclass, you might have to do the following in layoutSubviews: self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

Comment: It's working only for first "collection" of cells. When you add new cell there, separators are "free to go"

Comment: For Xamarin IOS C# it will be tableView.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

Comment: This answer didn't work for me in iOS8. This did...`tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method: `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

Comment: How this isn't default behavior BAFFLES me. Looking for an iOS 8 solution, as neither this nor the comment directly above mine seems to be working.

Comment: I can't post the ios 8/xcode 6 solution because the question is locked. But you can find a solution for ios 8/xcode 6 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working

Comment: I can't post the Swift version, working and tested on iOS 7 and 8, because the question is locked. But you can find this solution here: http://bit.ly/1HzXBis

Comment: @Tim Awesome comment.Please post it as an answer as this is the only straightforward method working in iOS8.

Answer (score 236):

This is default by iOS7 design. try to do the below:

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

You can set the '**Separator Inset**' from the storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For other users, note that the default value of this is "Default". You need to change it to "Custom" in order to be able to edit the inset values.

Comment: [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; is probably a better idea

Comment: Hope there will be more gif like this one in stack overflow

Comment: This acts weird in iOS 8. I set it to 0 but nothing changed. But I increased it to 50, it worked! I tried setting it to 0 from code too but no. Can anyone confirm this? I'm on Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: Okay I tested this in both iOS 7 and iOS 8. Here are the results - [iOS 7](http://i.imgur.com/czINe0t.png), [iOS 8](http://i.imgur.com/2xgOd3d.png). As you can see in iOS 7 it works as expected but there is a glitch in iOS 8, the custom inset is applied only to the cell with no text.

Comment: I see the same thing @Isuru. Hopefully it will be addressed in beta 5. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: @Joey Yeah, hope so. And yes, I did file a bug.

Comment: I have posted a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25088632/1077789).

Comment: Didn't work for me either, in iOS 8.

Comment: Im working in Xcode6 beta 4 and when setting separator insets to 0 for both left and right there is still a small gap on the left.

Comment: Working in xcode6 beta6 and iOS 7 and there is a gap on the left whatever I do - storyboard or code.

Comment: still happening on the iOS 8 GM build. I fixed it by adding a a UIView with height of 1px to the bottom of my cells. To mimic default colour colours I made the view's colour white and alpha = 0.2

http://puu.sh/bvFnU/a64f1e52f5.png

Comment: I concur, doctor. iOS8 doesn't honor UIEdgeInsetsZero :(

Comment: any solutions for xcode 6.0.1 ?

Comment: I can't post the ios 8/xcode 6 solution because the question is locked. But you can find a solution for ios 8/xcode 6 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS9/XCode 7 either.