# separator line is not showing properly while setting text to tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an app in which i am using tableview. but i am stuck in some issue that is when i am setting text to my cell, separator line is showing after some space from left below is my screen shot
[image: first five cell showing spaces from left while remaining are ok]

What i am mistaking ???
below is my sample code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=@"demo";

    return cell;

   }
```

Thanx in advance... please help as i am stuck in it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the inset if you want to use full width

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if ([self.tableview respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.tableview setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.tableview respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.tableview setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    } 
}
```

If using storyboard you can edit the inset as shown on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773239/how-to-fix-uitableview-separator-on-ios-7)

[image]

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: but when i set text to my cell it space is present.. otherwise it is showing fine as i showed in my screen shot.

Comment: Try changing the separator insets on the storyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65617/discussion-between-mishal-awan-and-vig).