# Q: Custom TableViewCell scroll to not see, and show again ,my custom line dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two different `custom cell` in my `tableview`, In the first cell I add a custom cell line under the system cell line:

```
_bottom_line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 49, kScreen_Width, 1)];
_bottom_line.backgroundColor = Back_Color_QQ;
[part3 addSubview:_bottom_line];
```

In the `controller` to setup my custom cell;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {  // my first cell
        
        static NSString *id_cell1 = @"cell1";
        AgDetailTechCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:id_cell1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[AgDetailTechCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:id_cell1];
        }
        
        ((AgDetailTechCell *)cell).model = self.headerModel;
        ((AgDetailTechCell *)cell).indexPath = indexPath;
        ((AgDetailTechCell *)cell).delegate = self;
        _head_cell = cell;
        
        _head_cell.comemntCountlabel.text = self.headerModel.lml_commentTimes;
        _head_cell.likeCountlabel.text = self.headerModel.lml_likeTimes;
        
        return cell;
    }else {  // other cells
    
        static NSString *id_cell2 = @"cell2";
        AgPreOrHelpCommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:id_cell2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            //cell = [[AgPreOrHelpCommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:id_cell2];
            cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AgPreOrHelpCommentCell" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
        }
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        [cell initCellDataWithModel:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
        
        
        cell.refresh = ^(UITableViewCell *currentCell) {
            
        
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            
             [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
            
        };
        
        
        return cell;
    }
    
}
```

The first time into the controller, it shows well. But after I scroll my `tableview` to hide and show again, my custom bottom line dismiss, I cannot find it.And I refresh my tableView, the custom line appears again. I have token 2 pictures to explain more detail:

**UPDATE**
Use Harsh's suggestion, but no change for the issue:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"cell1"]) {
        // customs bottom_line
         UIView * bottom_line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 49, kScreen_Width, 1)];
        bottom_line.backgroundColor = Back_Color_QQ;
        
        [((AgDetailTechCell *)cell).part3 addSubview:bottom_line];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try to add the lines in the `willDisplayCell` dataSource method. I hope you will get the right result.

Comment: @Harsh I have taken your suggestion, but it shows no change, thanks all the time.

Comment: Could you highlight in the image which line you are talking about.

Comment: @Harsh In my update code.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, i wanted you to point it on the image which you have attached. I am not able to see the lines in the images you are talking about.

Comment: @Harsh I have update my image, thanks your remind.BTW, I take your method, I found if I scroll my` tableview` down to dismiss the first cell and up to show it, it is well, but I up to dismiss the first cell and down to show it, it will goes wrong .

Comment: The reason for adding this kind of line is to make the separator appear end to end?

Comment: @Harsh. Right, our UI want the line reach the left and right.

Comment: Then my dear friend your approach of adding your own line is totally incorrect. Apple provides a way to extend the default line. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773239/how-to-fix-uitableview-separator-on-ios-7

Comment: @Harsh, Ohh, Harsh, So I'm ignorant to the extend the default line.

Comment: So does this solve your purpose?

Comment: @Harsh , I found the kind link I have read before, and I cannot make a positive cell to expand its bottom line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120648/discussion-between-qq726535609-and-harsh).

Answer (score 1):

If your soul purpose is to extend the default separators from end to end.

Check this post [How to fix UITableView separator on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773239/how-to-fix-uitableview-separator-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your bottom line is out of your cell. Make sure you return 50 or greater height for cells. Another thing is disable the system bottom line of UITableView.

Comment: I have `lldb` the cell, its height no change, and I `capture view hierarchy `, it shows no my `custom bottom line`.

Comment: Was the bottom line removed from it's superview? You'd better make a demo project for this issue. Then we well be able to debug it.