# UIImage in TableViewCell pushes Cell Separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've added a UIImage to my table view cell. However, the UIImage is pushing the separator over to the right to make room for the UIImage. I'd like to find a way to have the separator include the UIImage and not be pushed over. Here is a picture of my table view cell.

[image]

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method with code for the image:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

   Exercise *tempPlaceholder = [exercisesInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



   NSString *exerciseDisplayName = tempPlaceholder.exerciseName;

   exerciseDisplayName = [exerciseDisplayName capitalizedString];

    exerciseDisplayName =
   [exerciseDisplayName  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_"
                                                withString:@" "];

   cell.textLabel.text = exerciseDisplayName;

   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"quads.png"];


    return cell;
}
```

If anyone could help me with this I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365049/is-there-a-way-to-make-uitableview-cells-in-ios-7-not-have-a-line-break-in-the-s

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who runs into this problem, using:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

will fill the gap between the UIImage and the table cell separator.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the size of imageView frame

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10.0, 10.0);
```

Or change the height of cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return 40.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are experiencing will only occur on **iOS 7** where the separators have insets that by default change with image view size.

To remove this behaviour simply set the separator insets to zero. However the `separatorInset` property is available on `UITableView` from **iOS 7.0**

So you only have to remove the inset in iOS 7.

You can check whether the table view responds to `setSeparatorInset:` doing

```
if ([self.tableview respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) 
{
    [self.tableview setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```