# How can remove indentation in UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

First of all, I am new at this and I am most likely forgetting something very simple.

**Question:**

I am making an application that displays random images from imgur.com in a `tableView`.  For some reason all of the cells are indented a small amount as seen in the picture below. I have fiddled around with many settings in `storyboard` and have had no luck in fixing the issue.

[image: notice indent on left side of images]

Here is the tableView code...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return (_images.count * 2);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
//content cell
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RandomImgurTableCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"RandomImgurTableCell"];
    }

    long row = [indexPath row] / 2;

    SDImageCache* myCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    cell.imageView.image = [myCache imageFromDiskCacheForKey:_images[row]];

}
else if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
//separator cell
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SeparatorCell"];

    if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"SeparatorCell"];
    }
}
if (indexPath.row == (_images.count * 2) - 3) {
    [self checkToLoadMoreImages];
    NSLog(@"Hit bottom of table, getting more images");
}
return cell;
}
```

Here is a picture of my `tableView` and cell settings...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

In order to get rid of the indent, you set the separator insets to zero. The result is shown in the following image.

[image]

**In Code**

```
myTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

**In the Interface Builder**

[image]

**Notes**

If the cells are causing the indent, then you can add the following lines to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

If you are still supporting pre iOS 8 then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626312/3681880) for more details.

- See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365049/is-there-a-way-to-make-uitableview-cells-in-ios-7-not-have-a-line-break-in-the-s).

Answer (score 5):

Adjusting the **separator inset** should fix this. I believe that the default is `15px` in from the left.

Comment: This removed the separator inset, however the content of the cell is still indented.  At least I am part way there. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the horizontal indentation then you should try the following:

1. Make sure that the content view frame x origin is at 0:

   `yourTableViewCell.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, SOME_WIDTH, SOME_HEIGHT);`
2. You should make sure that the image view you're adding to the `UITableViewCell` is aligned with it's parent left edge. If you're using autolayout than do it in the interface builder. Otherwise:

   `yourImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`
3. See that when the image is scaled, it remains true to the view frame:

   `yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`
4. Make sure that the cell has 0 indentation:

   `yourTableViewCell.indentationLevel = 0;`

If none of this helps, set a breakpoint and examine the subviews of the cell using one of the following debugger command:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
po [yourTableViewCell recursiveDescription]
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, I found this instead:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-make-uitableviewcell-separators-go-edge-to-edge

> You need to do two things. First, add these two lines of code to your
> table view controller's viewDidLoad() method:
>
> ```
> tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero 
> tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
> ```
>
> Now look for your cellForRowAt method and add this:
>
> ```
> cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
> ```