# Background Color of View gradient

Tags: ios, swift, view, gradient

I have a problem with a view inside a tableViewCell. So I have a tableViewCell, inside of that I have a UIView I called "containerView". Now I want the background of the containerView to be a gradient from light gray to dark gray. In the following code you can see how I set the layer and everything, but for some reason the "backgroundColor" with the gradient is a little off to the right and downwards. Hope you can help me fix this problem, it's the first time I am working with gradient so please be patient :D

```
import UIKit

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let layerView = UIView()
    layerView.layer.frame = containerView.layer.frame
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.frame = containerView.layer.frame
    layer.colors = [UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor, UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor]
    layerView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    containerView.addSubview(layerView)
    containerView.sendSubviewToBack(layerView)

  }
}
```

Comment: check the start and end point on `CAGradientLayer` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAGradientLayer/endPoint

Comment: show some screenshot for " little off to the right and downwards"

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890793/how-can-remove-indentation-in-uitableview) will give you more insight on indentation

Comment: @beginner_T Please accept any of the given answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have assigned gradient color as background of my custom cell

```
let startingColorOfGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 217/255, green: 90/255, blue: 57/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let endingColorOFGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 227/255, green: 214/255, blue: 42/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y:1.0)
    gradient.colors = [startingColorOfGradient , endingColorOFGradient]
    // backGroundView is a View I have placed on my cell as container
    self.backGroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will assign gradient color to view background.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:38/255.0 green:154/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:30/255.0 green:88/255.0 blue:151/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This how i add gradient layer to canvasView(UIView) background. And background of UIView should be clear.

```
func addGradient(color:UIColor){
        let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame.size = self.canvasView.frame.size
        gradient.colors = [color.cgColor,color.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor] //Or any colors
        self.canvasView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
```