# -[UITableViewCell setLayoutMargins:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error in iphone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have one application and it is working fine in all version of iPhone except in iPhone 4. It is giving the below error.

```
-[UITableViewCell setLayoutMargins:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175f01b0
```

Can anyone help me what is the reason for this crash? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: My guess: `layoutMargins` is called, but it's only available since iOS8+ and you iPhone 4 is not on iOS8.

Comment: Check respondToSelector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365049/is-there-a-way-to-make-uitableview-cells-in-ios-7-not-have-a-line-break-in-the-s

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at UIView.h or UIView documentation [UIView layoutMargings property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins), you may notice that this property is only available for iOS 8 and above.

Once you are running your application on iPhone 4 and it is not intended to support this version of iOS (iOS 8)[iPhone 4 versions of iOS supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Highest_version_of_iOS_supported), you should perform validations on your code to check if the API method is available. You can also check the version of iOS, it's your choice.

I don't know your implementation, but as a quick fix you can check if the instance of the cell responds to the selector, and perform the correct implementation.

Example:

```
UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
if ([tableViewCell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    <# Your code here #>
}
```

To check the iOS version, you should use a macro or a function, just to keep your code simple. Just check here for more questions about: **How to check iOS version?** or check github repo **carlj/CJAMacros**

Hope that can help ;)