# Set beginning of Separator Lines in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

A UITableView has seperator lines as shown in the following image. They do not start at the beginning of the row. See the red box in the image. I want to change where they start.

[image]

**How can I specify where the separator lines in a table view begin?**

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365049/is-there-a-way-to-make-uitableview-cells-in-ios-7-not-have-a-line-break-in-the-s

Answer (score 2):

Add Table View Separator Insets to Zero.

[image]

Add this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (cell.respondsToSelector("preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins")){
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
}
```

See the preview :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " Not Just for Table View Cell"?

Comment: Select tableview not the cell. @confile

Comment: Why do I set the separator for the Table as well as for the TableViewCell? What is the difference?

Comment: @confile just set to tableview, don't set to cell :) That what I want to say

Comment: In which cases do I have to set it to the cell?

Comment: Please explain why you use ``preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins``for the cell.

Comment: I am not the person that explain the things. I just belong to the outputs. @confile Hope the answer will work for you.